# Anchor for each table row

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]

I'm trying to build this layout. I have this at this time: http://jsfiddle.net/Gh6mB/12/

Whats the best structure to use? I already have some problems using html table and also using only ul, li, and divs.
With tables, I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gh6mB/21/ The problem with this solution is that my a:hover effect doesn't work with #detalhes.

With html table, I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/KMjm6/8/ The problem with this version is that I can't put my anchor element as a child of tr. But I want to have each row as a anchor to other page.

I really appreciate any help, because I don't know what's the best way to develop this kind of site. Every strategy I use, I had some problem.

Comment: For the html tables you can put your anchor inside each td tag

Comment: One thing: never put block type elements into an `<a>` tag, like `div`, `h1`, etc., because it is not allowed by the standard, and some browsers actually misbehave (safari). Always use inline elements like `span` inside anchors. Also strictly follow the `table > table-row-group > table-row > table-cell` structure if you don't want to go mad.

Comment: Putting a anchor inside each td tag is ok for me. But I want to apply the hover effect in all the row at same time. It's possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it's a table of eventos, with one event per line, I resolved to use divs with the display table, table-row and table-cell.

Comment: Can you please elaborate and give some example html that solves the problem? Thanks.